# Using table.Rows.count in c# i don't think my database is connected

Tags: c#, mysql, database, authentication

I am trying to make my own login screen and registration and I got to the part where I want to know if the user exists. For some reason I create my user in my database and it keeps saying "no" when my user already exists.

I don't see what the problem is because I followed this youtube video and I understand the code so I really don't know why it doesn't work. I think my database is not connected because I am using a different port on xamp and I tried typing `localhost:3306` but that didn't work, I get an error, so I tried `localhost` but now I think it's not connected

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Krunsj_V1
{
    public partial class Officiallogin : Form
    {
        public Officiallogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Officiallogin(bool doNotMakeInvisibile)
        {                  
               InitializeComponent();                       
        }

        private void bunifuCustomLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Register Register = new Register();
            Register.ShowDialog();             
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DB db = new DB();

            String username = txtUsername.Text;
            String password = txtPassword.Text;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = @usn and 'password' = @pass", db.GetConnection());

            command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
            command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            adapter.Fill(table);


            // check if there user exists or not 
            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("YES");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO");
            }
            //Application.Exit();
            //Mainwindow main = new Mainwindow(true);
            //main.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            //main.ShowDialog();
        } 

        private void txtPassword_OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //txtPassword.isPassword = true;        
        }

        //////////////////////////////
        // close button properties  //
        //////////////////////////////
        private void lblclose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        private void lblclose_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblclose.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }

        private void lblclose_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblclose.ForeColor = Color.Purple;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it wasn't connecting properly then you'd get an exception. Are you sure that the username and password exists? (ps; do not store passwords in plain text)

Comment: Show use the `db.GetConnection()` code.  You might be looking at the wrong database if you aren't getting an exception.

Comment: In most languages you have a database connection string that would contain ports etc. I would imagine they would be properties of the adapter or db. Maybe that's the missing piece of the jigsaw. If you used something like DBeaver - (the equivalent of SSMS for SQL Server/Oracle Developer - but more generic), you setup a Connection with port/db schema you connect to, along with database user/pwd. That part appears missing. https://www.connectionstrings.com Do you have to associate the adapter with the db too?

Comment: I would put a breakpoint at "if (table.Rows.Count > 0)" and inspect the "command" and "adapter" variables. That may be a good starting point in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this SQL statement:

```sql
WHERE `username` = @usn and 'password' = @pass
```

`'password'` is a string literal, so you are asking if the user's parameterized password is the literal string `"password"`.

To quote a column name in MySQL, use backticks:

```sql
WHERE `username` = @usn and `password` = @pass
```

Or drop them entirely, since `username` and `password` aren't reserved words in MySQL:

```sql
WHERE username = @usn and password = @pass
```

Finally, this code implies that you're storing the users' plain text passwords directly in the database. This is a huge security vulnerability and should never be done. Research password hashing (e.g., at https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-passwords-one-way-road-to-security/) or use an off-the-shelf login system instead of trying to build your own.

Comment: thank you and i know see it my self eug so stupid mistake